# MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE will not fire unless breakpointed at MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN first

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

Brief description of my problem:

My motionevent, which appears to be correctly registered to the right view, fire `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` properly, but not `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

However, I accidentally discovered that if I place a breakpoint at `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` branch,  `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` starts to fire after I press F9(resume program).

I can't seem to decide what is causing all this. Can you help me? Below is the problematic code:

```
    public  class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static float sharedX,sharedY;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        sharedX = motionEvent.getX();
        sharedY = motionEvent.getY();

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

/*
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                return true;
  */

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Edit: it may have something to do with

```
ACTION_CANCEL,
```

which fires almost immediately after

```
ACTION_DOWN
```

and earlier than

```
ACTION_MOVE.
```

After I uncommented ACTION_CANCEL, it fires, and the program never reaches ACTION_MOVE.

So I now suspect that the reason ACTION_MOVE doesn't work is that it got ACTION_CANCEL -ed earlier and the whole motionevent simply quit.